# Directional Coupler Terminals

Tags: voltage, ground, transmission-line, wave, port

I have a basic question about directional couplers.

[image]

In this scheme each port is represented by one wire. What does it mean? The other terminal of each port is GND for all?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=directional+coupler It means the controlled impedance of 1 line per port with respect to the ground, not shown,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The other terminal of each port is GND for all?

Yes, that's it exactly.